# Why does my lp file give #number for each variable?

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I am using Ilog Cplex with Visual C++ 2015 to solve my problem. Generally, when I export lp file of my problem, the lp file will not contain any #number(such #0, #1, and so on) for variables. It is like this:

```
 \ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
 \Problem name: IloCplex

 Minimize
 obj: Ope(1,1,1) + Ope(1,1,2) + Ope(1,1,3) + Ope(1,1,4) + Ope(1,1,5)
  + Ope(1,1,6) + Ope(1,1,7) + Ope(1,1,8) + Ope(1,1,9) + Ope(1,1,10)
  + Ope(1,1,11) + Ope(1,1,12) + Ope(1,1,13) + Ope(1,1,14) + Ope(1,1,15)
  + Ope(1,1,16) + Ope(1,1,17) + Ope(1,1,18) + Ope(1,1,19) + Ope(1,1,20)
  + Ope(1,1,21) + Ope(1,1,22) + Ope(1,1,23) + Ope(1,1,24) + Ope(1,2,1)
  + Ope(1,2,2) + Ope(1,2,3) + Ope(1,2,4) + Ope(1,2,5) + Ope(1,2,6)
  + Ope(1,2,7) + Ope(1,2,8) + Ope(1,2,9) + Ope(1,2,10) + Ope(1,2,11)
  + Ope(1,2,12) + Ope(1,2,13) + Ope(1,2,14) + Ope(1,2,15) + Ope(1,2,16)
  + Ope(1,2,17) + Ope(1,2,18) + Ope(1,2,19) + Ope(1,2,20) + Ope(1,2,21)
  + Ope(1,2,22) + Ope(1,2,23) + Ope(1,2,24) + Ope(2,1,1) + Ope(2,1,2)
  + Ope(2,1,3) + Ope(2,1,4) + Ope(2,1,5) + Ope(2,1,6) + Ope(2,1,7)
  + Ope(2,1,8) + Ope(2,1,9) + Ope(2,1,10) + Ope(2,1,11) + Ope(2,1,12)
  + Ope(2,1,13) + Ope(2,1,14) + Ope(2,1,15) + Ope(2,1,16) + Ope(2,1,17)
  + Ope(2,1,18) + Ope(2,1,19) + Ope(2,1,20) + Ope(2,1,21) + Ope(2,1,22)
  + Ope(2,1,23) + Ope(2,1,24) + Ope(2,2,1) + Ope(2,2,2) + Ope(2,2,3)
  + Ope(2,2,4) + Ope(2,2,5) + Ope(2,2,6) + Ope(2,2,7) + Ope(2,2,8)
  + Ope(2,2,9) + Ope(2,2,10) + Ope(2,2,11) + Ope(2,2,12) + Ope(2,2,13)
  + Ope(2,2,14) + Ope(2,2,15) + Ope(2,2,16) + Ope(2,2,17) + Ope(2,2,18)
  + Ope(2,2,19) + Ope(2,2,20) + Ope(2,2,21) + Ope(2,2,22) + Ope(2,2,23)
  + Ope(2,2,24)
```

However, today I add some constraints to my model, the lp file gives #number to each variable. It is like this:

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name: IloCplex

Minimize
 obj: Ope(1,1,1)#0 + Ope(1,1,2)#1 + Ope(1,1,3)#2 + Ope(1,1,4)#3 + 
  Ope(1,1,5)#4
  + Ope(1,1,6)#5 + Ope(1,1,7)#6 + Ope(1,1,8)#7 + Ope(1,1,9)#8
  + Ope(1,1,10)#9 + Ope(1,1,11)#10 + Ope(1,1,12)#11 + Ope(1,1,13)#12
  + Ope(1,1,14)#13 + Ope(1,1,15)#14 + Ope(1,1,16)#15 + Ope(1,1,17)#16
  + Ope(1,1,18)#17 + Ope(1,1,19)#18 + Ope(1,1,20)#19 + Ope(1,1,21)#20
  + Ope(1,1,22)#21 + Ope(1,1,23)#22 + Ope(1,1,24)#23 + Ope(1,2,1)#24
  + Ope(1,2,2)#25 + Ope(1,2,3)#26 + Ope(1,2,4)#27 + Ope(1,2,5)#28
  + Ope(1,2,6)#29 + Ope(1,2,7)#30 + Ope(1,2,8)#31 + Ope(1,2,9)#32
  + Ope(1,2,10)#33 + Ope(1,2,11)#34 + Ope(1,2,12)#35 + Ope(1,2,13)#36
  + Ope(1,2,14)#37 + Ope(1,2,15)#38 + Ope(1,2,16)#39 + Ope(1,2,17)#40
  + Ope(1,2,18)#41 + Ope(1,2,19)#42 + Ope(1,2,20)#43 + Ope(1,2,21)#44
  + Ope(1,2,22)#45 + Ope(1,2,23)#46 + Ope(1,2,24)#47 + Ope(2,1,1)#48
  + Ope(2,1,2)#49 + Ope(2,1,3)#50 + Ope(2,1,4)#51 + Ope(2,1,5)#52
  + Ope(2,1,6)#53 + Ope(2,1,7)#54 + Ope(2,1,8)#55 + Ope(2,1,9)#56
  + Ope(2,1,10)#57 + Ope(2,1,11)#58 + Ope(2,1,12)#59 + Ope(2,1,13)#60
  + Ope(2,1,14)#61 + Ope(2,1,15)#62 + Ope(2,1,16)#63 + Ope(2,1,17)#64
  + Ope(2,1,18)#65 + Ope(2,1,19)#66 + Ope(2,1,20)#67 + Ope(2,1,21)#68
  + Ope(2,1,22)#69 + Ope(2,1,23)#70 + Ope(2,1,24)#71 + Ope(2,2,1)#72
  + Ope(2,2,2)#73 + Ope(2,2,3)#74 + Ope(2,2,4)#75 + Ope(2,2,5)#76
  + Ope(2,2,6)#77 + Ope(2,2,7)#78 + Ope(2,2,8)#79 + Ope(2,2,9)#80
  + Ope(2,2,10)#81 + Ope(2,2,11)#82 + Ope(2,2,12)#83 + Ope(2,2,13)#84
  + Ope(2,2,14)#85 + Ope(2,2,15)#86 + Ope(2,2,16)#87 + Ope(2,2,17)#88
  + Ope(2,2,18)#89 + Ope(2,2,19)#90 + Ope(2,2,20)#91 + Ope(2,2,21)#92
  + Ope(2,2,22)#93 + Ope(2,2,23)#94 + Ope(2,2,24)#95
```

I do not want #number to appear in my lp file. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LP file format does not allow arbitrary names for variables and/or constraints. You can find details in the user manual at [CPLEX > File formats > LP file format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html).

If *any* of your variables or constraints has a name that is not supported in the LP file format then this name has to be changed. To avoid the new name clashing with any existing name, CPLEX appends `#number` to *all* names in your model.

One likely/frequent unsupported name is a name that starts in `e`. Try to avoid such names in case you want to export to LP.